# Find word in a generated code that stored in hashset

Tags: java

Example generated code: 910love009tre

I would like to check if the generated code has a specific word inside it.
I'm trying to use the `contains`-method, but it looks like it doesn't give me the desired output.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class AlphaNumericExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    enter code here
    AlphaNumericExample example = new AlphaNumericExample();
    Set<String> codes = new HashSet<>();
    for (int x = 0;x< 100 ;x++ ) {

       codes.add(example.getAlphaNumeric(16));
    System.out.println(codes.contains("love"));//Im trying to check if the generated codes that have been stored in hashset have form a word 
    }

    System.out.println("Size of the set: "+codes.size());


  }

  public String getAlphaNumeric(int len) {

    char[] ch = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

    char[] c = new char[len];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();//
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      c[i] = ch[random.nextInt(ch.length)];
    }

    return new String(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that [Set.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) does something different then [String.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    String generated = example.getAlphaNumeric(16);
    codes.add(generated);
    System.out.println(generated.contains("love"));
}
```

Comment: @AlJaKe Open a new question for that.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the contains method checks if the entire object matches. Not if it contains that specific char sequence, so a 13 character object will never match a 4 letter sequence

instead of

```
System.out.println(codes.contains("love"));//Im trying to check if the generated codes that have been stored in hashset have form a word
```

try the contains method on each individual string, instead of the contains method of the HashSet

```
for (String code: codes) { 
    if  (code.contains("love")    {
     System.out.println("found!")       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the complete string "love" in the codes set. You need to check for it's presence in each code in the codes set. You can use streams for checking this.

```
boolean isPresent = codes.stream().anyMatch( code -> code.indexOf( "love" ) != -1 );
```